# Tkinter Issues Calling Another Script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having some trouble with a school project. The project involves running python code on a raspberry pi using a pi camera to "detect plaque". It really just picks up yellow in the pictures.

I apologize in advance I know absolutely nothing about coding, so I'm going to do my best to describe the problem and provide only the necessary information.

I am getting an error when I try to call one script using a tkinter button, but the script I'm trying to call works perfectly fine on its own. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PC_working_code/Final.py", line 54, in process
    import seniordesign_colordetect_trial
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PC_working_code/seniordesign_colordetect_trial.py", line 150, in <module>
    label=tki.Label(window,image=finalimg,width=600, height=450)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

I have one script that is basically just a GUI and a preview of the camera. This one is named "Final.py". It is calling another script that does all the analysis called "seniordesign_colordetect_trial.py". I will call this senior design for simplicity.

**Final** captures a picture with `cappic`. Then **Final** uses a tkinter GUI button to call **seniordesign**. Below is the important sections of **Final**.

```
    def cappic():
        camera.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/PC_working_code/image.jpg')
        webcam.release()
        img_new = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        cv2.waitKey(1650)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        img_ = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        img_resized = cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img-final.jpg', img=img_)
    
        
    button1 = tki.Button(window, text="Capture Teeth", height=4, width=30, bg="red", fg="white", 
    relief="solid", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), command=cappic)
    button1.place(x=40, y=600)


    def process():
        camera.stop_preview()
        import seniordesign_colordetect_trial
        camera.start_preview(fullscreen=False, window = (75,100,500,600))

    button2 = tki.Button(window, text="Process Picture", height=4, width=30, bg="red", fg="white",relief="solid", font=("arial", 24, "bold"),command=process) 
    button2.place(x=40, y=800)
```

The section of **seniordesign** that is causing the error is shown below. If I comment out the label then it works fine, but label is really the only part of the code that is important for what I need.

```
    window=tki.Tk()
    window.title("Results")
    window.geometry("650x1050+0-29")
    window.configure(background='white')
    cv2.imwrite(filename='image.jpg', img=imageFrame)

    finimg=Image.open('/home/pi/Desktop/PC_working_code/image.jpg')
    resizeimg=finimg.resize((600,450),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    finalimg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(resizeimg)

    label=tki.Label(window,image=finalimg,width=600, height=450)
    label.pack()

    def close():
        window.destroy() 

    button1=tki.Button(window, text="Take Another Picture", height=4, width=30, bg="red", fg="white", 
    relief="solid", font=("arial", 24, "bold"), command=close)
    button1.pack()
```

Any help would be fantastic. I am very lost and have not had any luck searching google.

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: Does `/home/pi/Desktop/PC_working_code/image.jpg` exist when you start running?  I see that it's captured by `cappic`.  You do have `cv2.imwrite(filename='image.jpg'...)`, but are you sure you're in the `Desktop` folder when that runs?

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: @TimRoberts it does exist but I have been having cappic overwrite the image. I believe I am in the `Desktop` when this runs because everything including the image is in the `PC_working_code` folder

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `Tk()`. Do you have it more than once?

Comment: It is called out once in `Final` and once in `seniordesign` but it seems to run fine with `Tk()` in both if I comment out the `tki.label` in `seniordesign`

Comment: That is the label that shows image, commenting it out, the image is never used and there is no such error. Remove any child `Tk()` and make it `Toplevel()`. Only keep one `Tk()`.

Comment: Using Toplevel worked thank you so much